# PHP syntax checking incorrect after update

Tags: php, syntax, aptana3

Running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.1.201204131931 on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

I just installed the latest update this morning and now notice that the syntax checking for PHP files is no longer working properly.

Here is a screenshot showing syntax errors and yet the script actually executes without issue. This didn't happen prior to the update.
[image]

Comment: Not a fix for your current issue, but with Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.1.201204131931 on Windows 7 Pro, my PHP file/syntax highlighting is correct. That is, I cannot reproduce your original issue of syntax errors when there are actually none. What happens if go to Source->format? Does that take away the false syntax errors?

Comment: Applying Source > Format did not resolve the issue. Neither did deleting the line and then undoing the deletion. After completely closing Aptana and then reopening the file everything displays properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the Aptana Studio application appears to have resolved the issue.